# Cannot start Visual Studio 2013 Community edition

Tags: visual-studio-2013

For a 64-bit PC...

Downloaded the installer vs_community.exe for Visual Studio 2013 with Update4 yesterday and ran it. It took about 1 hour and 20 minutes. At the end the installer reported the web deployment function could not be found/installed and that I could locate and install it myself later. It then told me to restart the PC, which I did, but the Community edition was not on the start menu.

There are other Visual Studio versions on this PC:

Visual C# 2010 Express, Visual Express 2012, Visual Express 2013 and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate trial version. They can all be started from the menu and do not interfere with each other and they all installed without problems. There are 4 weeks evaluation time left for VS 2013 Ultimate and I want to make use of that. The VS Express can go though if any of these might be blocking the Community version.

I am puzzled by one more VS directory named Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 in Program Files(x86). This contains many items added yesterday by the Community install including a directory named Community with with two files licence.htm and ThirdPartyNotices.txt. It also contains files and directories added in November last year (ImportProjects, Preemptive Solutions...(don't remember what I installed)) and some added in February this year when I installed VS Ultimate 2013 trial. So the VS 2012 directory 
contains a mix of items placed there by VS 2013 installers.

Questions:

1. Could this be the cause of the Community version not being on the Start menu?
2. what can I do to fix this without losing the VS Ultimate trial?